# JQuery wait a number of seconds before the next line of code is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a simple way or pausing a few seconds before the next line of code is executed.

So I have:

```
$('.myClass').show();

//WAIT FOR 5 SECONDS HERE

$('.myClass').hide();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`setTimeout`:

```
$('.myClass').show();
window.setTimeout(function (){$('.myClass').hide(); }, 5000);
```

<s>$('.myClass').show().delay(5000).hide();</s>

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

In order to use `delay` you have to use duration so it will use the queue:

```
$('.myClass').show().delay(5000).hide(0);
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NfTEV/3/)

**Thanks @am not i am!** (again...)

Comment: Exactly, and to copy/paste the JQuery function info :
The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: Your first code example isn't correct. The `.hide()` method isn't a queued effect, so `.delay()` will have no impact on it. I was going to comment earlier, but I was curious to know how many upvotes you'd get for an incorrect answer. Sorry for using your answer as part of my experiment. ;)

Comment: ...[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/NfTEV/) to back up my claim. Note that in can be queued if you give it a duration.

Comment: Your first code does not work. Cant we use a call back function within show method, and write the delay code in there. It works that way but not probably the best way.$('.myClass').show(500, function(){ $(this)..delay(5000).hide()});

Comment: @amnotiam. Thanks! so how was the experiment? successful?

Comment: @user508518. `hide(1)` is better.

Comment: @gdoron: Yes, in a way. I think people like short, elegant snippets of jQuery code, and will vote for it even if they don't really know whether or not the code is correct. I kinda don't like the vote system here, but I guess nothing's perfect. I hope you don't feel that I was targeting you. The use of `.delay()` is commonly misunderstood. By the way, if you just do `.delay(5000).hide(0)`, it'll work.

Comment: ...ah, I see you already experimented with a short `.hide(1)` duration. :) +1 on your update.

Comment: @amnotiam. Changed from **1** to **0**. So Chuck norris won't notice the delay... =)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$('.myClass').show();
window.setTimeout(  
    function() {  
         $('.myClass').hide();//happens 5 secs later
    },  
    5000
);
```

See [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) on MDN

Comment: +1. You were right. Read my answer + comments again. You will learn something new... =)

Comment: :) Yep I did pretty immediately yesterday itself, interesting stuff!

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose the `hide` in a call to `setTimeout()`.

```
$('.myClass').show();
setTimeout(function() {$('.myClass').hide()}, 5000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout($('myClass').hide, 5000);` doesn't work as expected.  You should use `setTimeout(function(){$('myClass').hide()}, 5000);` instead

Comment: @Rocket. His code could work. `setTimeout("$('myClass').hide()", 5000);`

Comment: @Rocket and gdoron. Good calls, thanks. I prefer to pass the function object instead of the string. Good notes all the way around.

Comment: better use `window.setTimeout` instead of `setTimeout` **=)**

Comment: @gdoron: Don't ever pass strings to `setTimeout`  It uses, `eval`, which is `evil`, also `window.setTimeout` vs `setTimeout` shouldn't matter.

Comment: `setTimeout($('myClass').hide, 5000);` doesn't work because the function is called with the wrong context (`this` is set to `window`).

Comment: @gdoron. I see the explicit reference `window.setTimeout()` some, and the implicit reference `setTimeout()` some. I really don't have  preference, but why is the explicit better? If so, I'll start coding that way. Thanks, man.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but you forgot the `.` in the selector... `$('myClass')` => `$('.myClass')`.

Comment: @gdoron Well as long as you don't (and nobody should IMHO) override the settimeout function, I prefer forget the extra `window.`. But if you use external library, then it would be worse the effort.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.myClass').show();

window.setTimeout(function () {
   $('.myClass').hide();
}, 5000);
```